# Powershell for GitHub setup

Tags: powershell, github-for-windows

I just installed GitHub for windows and for convenience I added entries for the powershell in the context menu in Windows Explorer. The registry commands are:

```
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit 
C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath '%L'
```

As suggested in shell.ps1 I added ". (Resolve-Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\GitHub\shell.ps1")" to my profile.ps1 to get poshgit and the rest setup within my powershell environment. It is not completely working though. I can see that shell.ps1 was executed (when running "$env:github_posh_git" I see the right value appearing) but when I navigate to a git repo I do not see the enhanced prompt.

**What am I missing?**

**PS**: The only version of Powershell I have came with GitHub for windows and even though the folder says "1.0" running

```
 $psversiontable.psversion
```

returned

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1
```

Comment: Ignore the name of the folder.  It still says v1.0 for PowerShell v3 and the v4 preview.

Comment: Where have you placed your profile.ps1 file?  It should be in `$Home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell`.

Comment: @KeithHill The profile.ps1 file is where you mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got an answer from GitHub support:

The enhanced prompt is provided by posh-git [1], and it isn't added when you run the line in shell.ps1. However, it's easy enough to install.

Just cd to C:\Users\Username\AppData\GitHub\PoshGit_* and run the install.ps1 script from PowerShell. It will add it to your PowerShell $profile automatically.

Comment: Depending on network config, you may have to cd to "C:\Users\Username\AppData\local\GitHub\PoshGit_*"